# creating one new vector from a list with 3 vectors in it, but eliminate duplicate values

Tags: r, list, unique

I have a list that contains multiple lists of three vectors

That prints:

```
 [[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[1] 1 2

[[1]][[2]]
[1] 1 3

[[1]][[3]]
[1] 2 3


[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
[1]  4 5

[[2]][[2]]
[1]  5 6

[[2]][[3]]
[1] 4 6
```

I want to create two vectors:

```
c(1, 2, 3), c(4, 5, 6)
```

I have also tried to `unique(unlist(x))` which works but loses the references to the positions within the list.  I have multiple lists within my lists, so when I apply `unique(unlist(list(x)))` it just creates one string.  I want to keep my vector `c(1, 2, 3)` separate from the next list of `c(4, 5, 6)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there. You just need to apply your solution to all the lists separately.

```
lapply(lst, function(x) unique(unlist(x)))

#[[1]]
#[1] 1 2 3

#[[2]]
#[1] 4 5 6
```

**data**

```
lst <- list(list(c(1, 2), c(1, 3), c(2, 3)), list(c(4,5), c(5, 6), c(4, 6)))
```